# Pulling db from heroku to local db

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-dump

I am trying to pull my pg database on heroku into my local development database. I am running

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL LOCAL_POSTGRE --app MY_APP
```

Unfortunately I get :

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.5.4; pg_dump version: 9.4.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

What's going on ? How can I fix that ?